# How to make a 3-d like visualization of a CNN model developed using pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, visualization

Currently, I have a CNN model that I developed in Pytorch. I have used hiddenlayer package to create an image like shown in image 1. But, I want to create an image of the model that should look like something in image 2. Is there any package that I can use to achieve this?

image 1:

[image: image 1]

image 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use figma.com and "draw" it myself, but if you want to create it automatically you should check out [this](https://github.com/ashishpatel26/Tools-to-Design-or-Visualize-Architecture-of-Neural-Network) github repository, you might find a nice tool.

Comment: That was really helpful. Thanks!